# How to fixed header-footer in elgg

Tags: php, themes, elgg

I Have Integrate one **HTML Theme** in **ELgg**.
    but header-footer are not fixed its place.

How to fixed them?
    can any file have changed for that in **ELgg** ?

How to fixed header-footer for all pages?

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tired?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have integrate one html theme in elgg index.php created in elgg theme, that header footer are not fixed... so i will try to fixed header-footer, but whene i jump to another page like login header are display default elgg header, not display my custome theme header-footer

Comment: header-footer are fixed for all pages in elgg